# What fieldtype should I use to select one item from a bucket

Tags: content-editor, buckets

I have a template in which I want to provide a field where editors can select 1 item from a bucket. I am just not sure which field type I should use. The best match for working with buckets seems to be the "Multilist with Search", but that is more suited for selecting multiple items and I need only (and max) 1.

Does anyone have any experience on this - where your editors were happy with the result?

Comment: This was also asked on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30503267/61470

Comment: The question was phrased differently but the answers are indeed valid. Thx.

Comment: I made a project that adds search enabled fields: https://github.com/Barsonax/SitecoreSearchFields Currently there is both a SingleLink and a MultiLink which both offer the same rich search interface you normally get for buckets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used a multilist with search and just used a regex in the validate field to limit to choices to the field requirements know each case.

Here is an example regex that limits zero to 5 items `^({[^}]+}|?){0,5}$`

For zero to 1 item change the `0,5` to `0,1`. To force one item set to `1,1`.

Src [blog post by Ben Ramey](http://www.benramey.com/2012/06/12/limit-selected-items-on-sitecore-multilist-field/)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the regex validation? How would do I do that to allow only one result?

Comment: Updated the answer as best I can. The mobile app is hard to use!

Comment: This seems to work fine with Content Editor but not with Custom experience Field Editor buttons in Experience Editor. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such field. It's probably a good thing to suggest for Sitecore though as it's not my first time I see such request. The way I see it you have two options

1. implement the custom field
2. use a mix of multilist with search with validation to limit the amount of items you can associate with the field(not the best choice but it is a workaround that works)